# How to auto click using jquery if the value exist

Tags: javascript

I have the following code which check for session storage value but it seem to always go to else instead of if. even though the value exists.

```
 var state= open;// i meant where var state = open
      var state =sessionStorage.getItem("state");
       //state ===open ? openAllViolations().click() : closeAllViolations().click();
        console.log(" opened val for session " +state);
        if(sessionStorage.getItem("state")==open) {

            openAllViolations().click();
            console.log(" OPEN") 

        }else {


            console.log(" CLOSE") 


        }
```

Comment: What does `where state = open` mean? That's not valid Javascript.

Comment: Is this line a typo? `where state= open`?  Should that be `var state = open`.  That said, what is the value of `open`. If the code always goes to the else part, than open does not equal the value of state.

Comment: Is this valid javascript?  Also, what is the value of the open variable?

Comment: your title != your question

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing quotes around `open`

```
 if(sessionStorage.getItem("state")=="open") {

            openAllViolations().click();
            console.log(" OPEN") ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't suggest doing this, but this is what you are looking for:

```
document.getElementById('openAllViolations').click();
```

I guess that openAllViolations is an element of your DOM. Other way to do this is to execute a function.

```
where state= open
      var state =sessionStorage.getItem("state");
       //state ===open ? openAllViolations().click() : closeAllViolations().click();
        console.log(" opened val for session " +state);
        if(sessionStorage.getItem("state")==open) {

            openAllViolations();
            console.log(" OPEN") 

        }else {


            console.log(" CLOSE") 


        }



   function openAllViolations() {
        //do something
   }
```